# List of a Type Classe instance

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, ghc, functional-dependencies

I've been playing around with Haskell type classes and I am facing a problem I hope someone could help me to solve. Consider that I come from a Swift background and "trying" to port some of protocol oriented knowledge to Haskell code.

Initially I declared a bunch of JSON parsers which had the same structure, just a different implementation:

```haskell
data Candle = Candle {
  mts :: Integer,
  open :: Double,
  close :: Double
}

data Bar = Bar {
  mts :: Integer,
  min :: Double,
  max :: Double
}
```

Then I decided to create a "Class" that would define their basic operations:

```haskell
class GenericData a where
  dataName :: a -> String
  dataIdentifier :: a -> Double
  dataParsing :: a -> String -> Maybe a
  dataEmptyInstance :: a


instance GenericData Candle where
  dataName _ = "Candle"
  dataIdentifier = fromInteger . mts
  dataParsing _ = candleParsing
  dataEmptyInstance = emptyCandle

instance GenericData Bar where
  dataName _ = "Bar"
  dataIdentifier = fromInteger . mts
  dataParsing _ = barParsing
  dataEmptyInstance = emptyBar
```

My first code smell was the need to include "a" when it was not needed (`dataName` or `dataParsing`) but then I proceded.

```haskell
analyzeArguments :: GenericData a => [] -> [String] -> Maybe (a, [String])
analyzeArguments [] _             = Nothing
analyzeArguments _ []             = Nothing
analyzeArguments name data
    | name == "Candles" = Just (head possibleCandidates, data)
    | name == "Bar" = Just (last possibleRecordCandidates, data)
    | otherwise  = Nothing

possibleCandidates :: GenericData a => [a]
possibleCandidates = [emptyCandle, emptyBar]
```

Now, when I want to select if either instance should be selected to perform parsing, I always get the following error

```haskell
• Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘Candle’
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      possibleCandidates :: forall a. GenericData a => [a]
    at src/GenericRecords.hs:42:29
```

My objective was to create a list of instances of `GenericData` because other functions depend on that being selected to execute the correct `dataParser`. I understand this has something to do with the type class checker, the `* -> Constraint`, but still not finding a way to solve this conflict. I have used several GHC language extensions but none has solved the problem.

Comment: I think the code smell here is maybe your type class. Anytime I see type classes whose methods all take `a` as the first argument, I get suspicious that someone is trying to shoehorn object oriented classes into Haskell type classes. It probably sounds like you want to put the `Bar` and `Candle` constructors under the same ADT.

Comment: I think this will quickly descend towards a known [antipattern](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/).

Comment: Two comments on what's gone wrong (without proposing a solution). 1. Lists are homogeneous (all elements have the same type), so `[emptyCandle, emptyBar]` is right out. 2. The type `Foo a => [a]` gives the user of this value control over which instance of `Foo` is chosen; the implementer has to be prepared to produce a list of values of *any* type which is an instance of `Foo`, whereas you seem to be thinking that the implementer of this type gets to choose *their favorite* type which is an instance of `Foo`.

Comment: @Alec yes, I agree, I was trying to bring the swift "protocol" style to Haskell, which at some point it has kicked me back saying NO, specially when I had to declare the instance on both sides of the declaration, which seemed weird for me,

Comment: @chi I agree with that blog post, here is another very very related to the same topic: http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/05/scrap-your-type-classes.html

Comment: @DanielWagner: my expectation was to have an homogeneous list of type "GenericData" that I can pass along functions, then use their declared "dataParsing" to transform the string into an instance of that object, however that is showing to not behave well at runtime.

Comment: To compile it would need to be `possibleCandidates = [dataEmptyInstance, dataEmptyInstance]`

Comment: @Invoke That would be fine. There's just one problem: `GenericData` is not a type.

Answer (score 2):

You have a type signature:

```
possibleCandidates :: GenericData a => [a]
```

Which you might thing implies that you can put anything in that list as long as it is `GenericData`. But that is not the way Haskell's type system actually works. The value `possibleCandidates` can be a list of any type which has a `GenericData` class but every element of the list must be of the *same* type.

What the GHC error message is telling you (in its own special way) is that the first element of the list is a `Candle` so it thinks that the rest of the list should also be of type `Candle` but the second element is actually a `Bar`.

Now there are ways to make heterogeneous lists (and other collections) in Haskell, but it is almost never the right thing to do.

One typical solution to this problem is to just merge everything down into one [sum data type](https://wiki.haskell.org/Algebraic_data_type):

```
data GenericData = GenericCandle Candle | GenericBar Bar
```

You could even forgo the step of indirection and just put the Candle and Bar data directly into the data structure.

Now instead f a class you just have a datatype and your class functions become normal functions:

```
dataName :: GenericData -> String
dataIdentifier :: GenericData -> Double
dataParsing :: GenericData -> String -> Maybe a
dataEmptyInstance :: String -> GenericData
```

There are some other more complex ways to make this work, but if a sum data type fits the bill, use it. It is very common for parsers in Haskell to have a large sum data type (usually also recursive) as their result. Take a look at the [`Value`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.2.2.0/docs/Data-Aeson-Types.html#t:Value) type in [Aeson](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson) the standard JSON library for an example.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar your solution based on this blog post:
http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/05/scrap-your-type-classes.html